# How to say the results of something in the past

Tags: sentence-construction

In the following sentences I try to state the result of something in the past. I'm not sure if they need *would* or not, or if I use the right tense

> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never tried to teach me math in an easy and sweet way *so that I became attracted to it*
>
> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never tried to teach me math in an easy and sweet way *so that it attracted me*

Comment: It is not clear what will be introduced by **so that**, the result of not having teachers who taught math in a sweet way, or what would have resulted had the teachers taught math in a sweet way. When we get to the end of the sentence, we realize that **so that** has introduced a hypothetical result, not a past actual result. So you'd need to say "so that I would have become attracted to it". Youj could also recast the so-that-clause as a restrictive that-clause in the active voice: *...in a way that got me interested*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The so-that clause can introduce the actual result:

> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never taught me math in a sweet
>   way, *so that I **never became attracted** to it*.

Or it can introduce a result that might have happened had things been different:

> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never taught me math in a sweet
>   way *so that I **would have become attracted** to it.*

The so-that clause can be an elaboration upon "never taught me" or an elaboration upon "sweet way". As a result of those two branches being possible, this is a little unclear:

> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never taught me math in a sweet
>   way *so that I **became attracted** to it.*

You can express the idea unambiguously with a simple restrictive that-clause:

> Unfortunately, I had bad teachers who never taught me math *in a way that got me interested in the subject*.